# using sed to extract certain strings from config file

Tags: string, awk, sed

I am trying to export certain strings from below output, however i have no experience with sed/awk and i need some advise how can i proceed with that.

Input:

```
name Cleartext-Password := "password", Service-Type := Framed-User
    Framed-IP-Address := 127.0.0.1,
    MS-Primary-DNS-Server := 8.8.8.8,
    Fall-Through = Yes,
    Mikrotik-Rate-Limit = 20M/30M
```

The output should be:
name;password;127.0.0.1;20M;30M;

I am not sure if this is correct way to do that, but i have tried to remove everything between my required string, for example:

```
sed 's/ Cleartext-Password := "/;/'
```

However i think this is dirty way and not the clever one.

Could you please let me know what i need to look for in order to create working sed/awk solution for this?

Comment: With only a single sample it's hard to say what would be adequate, but 5-6 lines of Awk seems like the ticket. If the tokens are always in predictable order, probably less. As such, this is unfortunately too vague to be an acceptable question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is `name` a keyword or a placeholder for a name which can contains spaces? Your file has always 5 rows?

Comment: @cyrus "name" is always a string without spaces, but it can own dots in it or other special characters.

Comment: This was tagged [tageembedded-linux] but you question has no mention of any platform. If you need this on a severely strapped platform like Busybox, perhaps [edit] to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @tripleee The config file contains like 300 records like the one i showed above. There are comments somewhere in the file but they start with # sign everytime, so i think they would be easy to exclude

Comment: Add 3-4 records and your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following based on your shown samples. Written and tested it in site
https://ideone.com/eWXv3w

Since OP's Input_file has control M characters so added  `gsub(/\r/,"")` in code here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS=";" }
{ gsub(/\r/,"") }
match($0,/Cleartext-Password[^,]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/Cleartext-Password[^"]*|"/,"",val)
  val=$1 OFS val
  next
}
/Framed-IP-Address/{
  sub(/,$/,"")
  val=val OFS $NF
  next
}
/Mikrotik-Rate-Limit/{
  print val, $NF
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** In `BEGIN` section of program setting `OFS` to semi colon as per question. Then using `match` function of awk to match regex from string Cleartext...`Cleartext-Password[^,]*` till first comma comes. If regex matches perfectly then capturing that sub-string in variable val here. Now using `gsub` to globally substitute everything from Cleartext-Password and all un-necessary stuff there as per required output.

Then checking if line contains `Framed-IP-Address` if it's found then send substituting `,` from last of line and adding that line last field to variable val here.

Now checking condition if a line contains `Mikrotik-Rate-Limit` then simply printing value of val and last field here, nullifying val here too.

Comment: Written this in mobile will add complete explanation in morning as it's late night now :)

Comment: `;20M/30Msword;127.0.0.1,`- This is the output i get testing on my debian lab

Comment: @jakeiscool, sorry I didn't get it, if you check my link mentioned in my solution it worked fine for me, could you please do let me know if you are getting any error here??

Comment: @jakeiscool, strange. Could you please check if you have control M characters in your Input_file? Please run like `cat -v Input_file` and let us know if you see any control m characters there?

Comment: There are no errors at all, sorry sir but i cant paste the whole output in the comment, so i pastebin it - https://pastebin.com/8a8BQzni

Comment: There are ^M characters at the end of every line

Comment: @jakeiscool, ok I knew it :) please run my edited code now where I have taken care of removing control m chars and let me know then?

Comment: @jakeiscool, could you please do let me know if you have checked my edited code now on my answer? It's quite late night here do asking you to confirm soon:)

Comment: Sir, now it works like a charm. Thank you soooo much. Sadly i have no clue how to even start understanding how your solution works. It looks so complex and hard to me. A lot of stuff for me to learn.. Thank you again

Comment: @jakeiscool, I have added detailed explanation in my answer now, kindly do check once and let me know in case of any queries cheers

Comment: @jakeiscool, for learning `awk` please check link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info cheers and happy learning

Comment: Hello Sir! It is me again. Your solution works perfectly, however i have encountered one issue and i need advise if it is possible to fix it. Sometimes there are # lines in between the records and AWK takes them and translates incorrectly, please check this example: https://pastebin.com/8RJcCCGK - If its possible to modify this AWK to  completely ignore lines starting with #? As my file has ~300 records like the example one and its very easy to get confused. We have temporary fixed it by moving all of the comments to end of the records, however i wonder if i can fix it somehow :)

Comment: @jakeiscool, hey Jake, sorry for late reply got busy in some work. on SO we its encouraged to ask one question per post only, so please do open a new thread adding samples and your efforts in it and let me know then cheers and happy learning on SO.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to approach this with `awk`, the key is to match part of the record with the regular expression to identify the record you are operating on and then isolate the wanted test and output in the desired format.

One approach would be:

```
awk '
    /Cleartext-Password/ { printf "%s;%s;", $1, substr($4,2,length($4)-3) }
    /Framed-IP-Address/  { printf "%s;", substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1) }
    /Mikrotik-Rate-Limit/{ sub(/\//,";",$NF); printf "%s;\n", $NF }
' config
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample input in the file named `config`, you would receive:

```
name;password;127.0.0.1;20M;30M;
```

Look things over and let me know if I misunderstood anywhere.

Comment: Thank you sir, i was sure that my question will be deleted but i appreciate all effort that You and others users put in helping me. I will check how your solution works and then try to understand every piece of it.

Comment: [GNU Awk - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) will provide you with all the functions used. The `/match-stuff/{...}` just ensures what comes between the `{...}` is only applied to the line containing `"match-stuff"`. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE -e '/Cleartext-Password/{s/ .*:=\s"(.*)",.*/;\1/;h}' \
        -e '/Framed-IP-Address/{s/.*:= (.*),/\1/;H}' \
        -e '/Mikrotik-Rate-Limit/{s#.*= (.*)/(.*)#\1;\2#;H;g;y/\n/;/;p}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by invoking the `-n` option.

Reduce back slashes by invoking the `-E` option.

Stash the fields of the record in the hold space and when all fields have been collected, copy the hold space to the pattern space, replace newlines by the field separators and print the result.

You may prefer:

```
sed -nE '/Cleartext-Password/{s/ .*:=\s"(.*)",.*/;\1/;h};
         /Framed-IP-Address/{s/.*:= (.*),/\1/;H};
         /Mikrotik-Rate-Limit/{s#.*= (.*)/(.*)#\1;\2#;H;g;y/\n/;/;p}' file
```

Comment: Hello! I have tested your solution, however it seems to act exactly as the RavinderSingh13 one. It cuts the password and first string, probably due to ^M existence in my test files. Please check: https://pastebin.com/PbzYrCTe

Comment: Try running `dos2unix <file` and pipe the result through to the sed command (without the `file` parameter).